# Setting node layoutProperty() in FXML

Tags: java, layout, javafx, fxml

I'm creating a UI for a project in javafx. I'm using CSS for the styles, FXML for the structure, and also .java controllers. I'm trying to make my node(s) (i.e. button, borderpane) layout bind to the scene size, so that the window can be resized and the layout stay the same. Normally if the node was defined in a jar file I would use:

`button.layoutYProperty().bind((scene.heightProperty().divide(2)));`

or something similar, but my nodes are defined within the FXML file. 
How  can I access the nodes from outside of the FXML file so that I can define the layout or how can I define the layout within the FXML file.
(I am not using and do not intend to use scene builder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should never need to do things like this. If you use [layout panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/builtin_layouts.htm#JFXLY102) you should always be able to choose a combination of layout panes and settings that automatically position the nodes as you want them. The solutions outlined below should never really be needed.

In the controller, you typically don't have direct access to the `scene`, so you need to listen for when the `sceneProperty()` is initialized on the node and act accordingly:

```
public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private Button button ;

    public void initialize() {

        button.sceneProperty().addListener((obs, oldScene, newScene) -> {
            button.layoutYProperty().unbind();
            if (newScene != null) {
                button.layoutYProperty().bind(newScene.heightProperty().divide(2));
            }
        });

        // ...
    }
}
```

But again, the correct approach here is to choose appropriate layout panes to achieve what you want.

Comment: I assume by your edit that the FXML method does not work, since you recommend just using layout panes, I will need to size the layout panes dynamically in order for it to scale correctly. Will the same approach as your initial answer work for this ?  and is there a FXML method for dynamic node(layout pane) scaling ?

Comment: @user2370794 Yes, I tested the FXML version and it didn't work (basically, when the scene was null, as it is initially, it threw a null pointer exception). There really is no reason you would have to size the layout panes using this technique (though of course it would work too). Any node is sized and positioned by its parent, according to its parent's layout strategy. So just place the layout pane in an appropriate layout pane, etc etc. The root pane is forced to be the same size as the scene. This really sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377).